# Why v-model not working when used in vue.extend?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I have a page structure similiar to this:

```html
<main id="app">
  <div id="mount-place"></div>
</main>
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
  ...some code here...
  <input type="text" v-model="address">
  ...some other code here...
</script>
<script>
var ExtendedElement = Vue.Extend({
  template: '#my-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      address: {{ some_address|safe }};  // gets values from django
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.address);  // Works just fine
  }
});
new ExtendedElement().$mount('#mount-place');
</script>
...some unimportant logic here...
<script>
const app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#app'
});
</script>
```

And the problem is it renders just fine, but `v-model` not working i.e. input shows nothing. When accessing it via console it shows values inside vue object. No errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is calling `new Vue`. Solution is just deleting `app` variable and move delimiters to `Vue.Extend` call.